# Dynamic table naming in Power-shell script or in SSIS

Tags: powershell, ssis

Is there a way to pass table name dynamically from power-shell script while deploying packages into MSDB. Source table name changes based on the environment we pull data from ..

Ex:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0WhS.jpg)

as you shown above we have different table name for different environment for same table. (Ex:Product table)

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try config file and dynamic sql in a variable. This is a ssis answer